# Are cookies secure from local access on the user's computer?

Tags: javascript, html

The book says "When a user visits a website, the browser locates and cookies written by that website and sends them to the server. Cookies may be accessed only by web server and scripts of the website from which the cookies originated (i.e a cookie set by a script on amazon.com can be read only by amazon.com servers and scripts) The browser sends these cookies with every request to the server."

Is this really true. I mean cookies is just text files without any type of security so anyone can read the cookie as long as they know the name ov the cookie.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-deal-with-cookies-in-javascript/

Comment: I changed your question title a bit - if it doesn't accurately reflect what you mean, feel free to roll back

Comment: Web browsers generally have tools that allow the user to look at any and all cookies set by any sites the user has visited.  It's safe to assume that all text of every cookie you send to a user will be visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean *anyone with access to the computer on which the user is browsing* and more specifically, the user's account there, then you are right - cookies are just text files and you just have to know where to find them. (Also many browsers allow viewing the current user's cookies.) There is very little security for cookies on this end, although they should usually not be accessible to anyone but admins and the user who did the browsing (but that is thanks to the filesystem security provided by the Operating System).

If you mean *anyone on the web,* like some other web site that the user navigates to, then the answer is no - the browser will not give cookies to anyone but the requesting site. (That's what the book is referring to when it says "nobody".)

Comment: This is not really true. Browsers have cookie viewers.

Comment: @Pointy yeah, that's a way easier way to see the cookies than scrounging for the text file. I thought about including that but it doesn't really change the point - if you have access to the user's files, you can view their cookies, one way or the other